# I would like to know how to add the page break to my table. I'm having a big problem with that

Tags: longtable

```
begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Principais trabalhos referente à pesquisa sobre hidratos, contemplando primeiro, segundo e terceiro período de estudos - ordem cronológica de 1778 à 2005.}

\begin{tabular}{{ llp{8cm} }}
    \hline
    \small
    \textbf{Ano} & \textbf{Autor} & \textbf{Observações} \\
    \hline
1778 & Priestley & Primeiro indicativo da formação de hidratos de dióxido de enxofre ($SO_2$) através da realização de experimentos a baixas temperaturas.  \\
1810 & Davy & Descobriu hidratos de cloro, com experimentos acima do ponto de solidificação da água.  \\
1823 & Faraday & Identificou as propriedades dos hidratos de gás cloro, com fórmula $Cl_2$.10$H_2$O. \\
1877 e 1882 & Cailletet e Bordet & Mediram pela primeira vez as propriedades dos hidratos gasosos mistos de $CO_2$ + $PH_3$ e de $H_2S$ + $PH_3$. \\
1883 & Wroblewski & Identificou pela primeira vez o hidrato de dióxido de carbono. \\
1888 e 1890 & Villard & Determinou a existência de hidratos de etano ($CH_4$), metano ($C_2$$H_6$) e propano ($C_3$$H_8$). E identificou o ponto quádruplo inferior. \\
1902 & de Forcrand & Estabeleceu as temperaturas de equilíbrio a 1 atm de 15 hidratos. \\
1934 e 1939 & Hammerschimidt & Identificou as causas do bloqueio de linhas de gás natural, sendo ocasionada por hidratos e descobriu os inibidores termodinâmicos. \\

\hline
1946 & Deaton e Frost & Realizaram experimentos de formação de hidratos a partir de componentes puros e misturas de metano ($CH_4$), etano ($C_2$$H_6$) e propano ($C_3$$H_8$).\\
1949 & Unruh e Katz & Reportaram as curvas de equilíbrio de hidratos para misturas de CO2 e CH4. \\
1951 & Kobayashi et al. & Apresentaram dados experimentais para inibição de sistemas na presença de NaCl e etanol. \\
1951 e 1952 & Claussen, Pauling e Marsh & Identificaram e nomearam duas diferentes estruturas cristalinas de hidratos como sI e sII. \\
1954 & von Stackelberg e Müller & Confirmaram, através de difração de Raio X, as estruturas cristalinas sI e sII e classificaram hidratos de CO2 como sI. \\

\hline
1965 e 1974 & Makogon & Documentou a descoberta de reservas de hidratos de metano na Sibéria, juntamente com a publicação do material Hidratos de Gás Natural.\\
1973 & Davidson & produziu o material “Clatratos Hidratos” na Água: Um Tratado Abrangente. \\
1980 & Kvenvolden e McMenamin & Descobriram a localização de hidratos em sedimentos rochosos no Alaska. \\
1987 & Ripmeester et al. & Descobriram a existência da estrutura sH. \\
1990 & Sloan & Produziu o material Clathrate Hidratos de Gases Naturais. \\
1995 & Kvenvolden & Realizou um estudo sobre a análise da Geoquímica do Metano no Hidrato de Gás Natural. \\
1997 & Spencer & Patenteou um método de separação seletiva de dióxido de carbono de sistemas multicomponentes \\
2000 & Seo et al. & Propuseram uma nova técnica de separação baseado em hidratos para recuperação do CO2 oriundo de combustão de motores. \\
2002 & Mallik & Primeira produção viável de gás a partir de hidratos. \\
2005 & Dallimore et al.& Realizou estudo “Relatório do experimento de campo internacional Mallik 5L sobre a recuperação de hidratos in situ do Permafrost”, relatório do Geological Survey of Canada. \\


        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tb:periodos}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can't have a page break within a table environment.  For that you need to use `longtable`, or one of the packages which extend the functionalities of `tabularx`, such as `ltablex` or `xltabular` .

Comment: Or you can use [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals), a package that break between pages automatically. Be aware that you cannot have a page breaking table in a table environment.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but please make sure you double-check the text corresponding to "Villard"  as the names and chemical formulae in this row don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using the `xltabular` package. I have removed the `table` environment, replaced `tabular` with `xltabular` and the `p` column by an `X` type column. I have also placed the `\caption` inside of the `xltabular` environment and used `\endfirsthead` and `\endhead` to control the table header on the first as well as on the following pages.

Lastly, I have loaded the `mhchem` package that allows to typeset chemical formulae. I have used this package for the formulae in the first 8 rows of the table. Adjusting the rest of the table is up to you. Personally, I'd also replaced the `\hlines` by the horizontal rules from the `booktabs` package as they come with a small vertical white space around them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{width=\textwidth}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}


%\begin{table}[h]
%    \centering

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{llX}
    \caption{Principais trabalhos referente à pesquisa sobre hidratos, contemplando primeiro, segundo e terceiro período de estudos - ordem cronológica de 1778 à 2005.}\label{tb:periodos} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Ano} & \textbf{Autor} & \textbf{Observações} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
        \hline
    \textbf{Ano} & \textbf{Autor} & \textbf{Observações} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
1778 & Priestley & Primeiro indicativo da formação de hidratos de dióxido de enxofre (\ce{SO_2}) através da realização de experimentos a baixas temperaturas.  \\
1810 & Davy & Descobriu hidratos de cloro, com experimentos acima do ponto de solidificação da água.  \\
1823 & Faraday & Identificou as propriedades dos hidratos de gás cloro, com fórmula \ce{Cl_2 * 10 H_2O}. \\
1877 e 1882 & Cailletet e Bordet & Mediram pela primeira vez as propriedades dos hidratos gasosos mistos de \ce{CO_2 + PH_3} e de \ce{H_2S + PH_3}. \\
1883 & Wroblewski & Identificou pela primeira vez o hidrato de dióxido de carbono. \\
1888 e 1890 & Villard & Determinou a existência de hidratos de etano (\ce{CH_4}), metano (\ce{C_2H_6}) e propano (\ce{C_3H_8}). E identificou o ponto quádruplo inferior. \\
1902 & de Forcrand & Estabeleceu as temperaturas de equilíbrio a 1 atm de 15 hidratos. \\
1934 e 1939 & Hammerschimidt & Identificou as causas do bloqueio de linhas de gás natural, sendo ocasionada por hidratos e descobriu os inibidores termodinâmicos. \\

\hline
1946 & Deaton e Frost & Realizaram experimentos de formação de hidratos a partir de componentes puros e misturas de metano ($CH_4$), etano ($C_2$$H_6$) e propano ($C_3$$H_8$).\\
1949 & Unruh e Katz & Reportaram as curvas de equilíbrio de hidratos para misturas de CO2 e CH4. \\
1951 & Kobayashi et al. & Apresentaram dados experimentais para inibição de sistemas na presença de NaCl e etanol. \\
1951 e 1952 & Claussen, Pauling e Marsh & Identificaram e nomearam duas diferentes estruturas cristalinas de hidratos como sI e sII. \\
1954 & von Stackelberg e Müller & Confirmaram, através de difração de Raio X, as estruturas cristalinas sI e sII e classificaram hidratos de CO2 como sI. \\

\hline
1965 e 1974 & Makogon & Documentou a descoberta de reservas de hidratos de metano na Sibéria, juntamente com a publicação do material Hidratos de Gás Natural.\\
1973 & Davidson & produziu o material “Clatratos Hidratos” na Água: Um Tratado Abrangente. \\
1980 & Kvenvolden e McMenamin & Descobriram a localização de hidratos em sedimentos rochosos no Alaska. \\
1987 & Ripmeester et al. & Descobriram a existência da estrutura sH. \\
1990 & Sloan & Produziu o material Clathrate Hidratos de Gases Naturais. \\
1995 & Kvenvolden & Realizou um estudo sobre a análise da Geoquímica do Metano no Hidrato de Gás Natural. \\
1997 & Spencer & Patenteou um método de separação seletiva de dióxido de carbono de sistemas multicomponentes \\
2000 & Seo et al. & Propuseram uma nova técnica de separação baseado em hidratos para recuperação do CO2 oriundo de combustão de motores. \\
2002 & Mallik & Primeira produção viável de gás a partir de hidratos. \\
2005 & Dallimore et al.& Realizou estudo “Relatório do experimento de campo internacional Mallik 5L sobre a recuperação de hidratos in situ do Permafrost”, relatório do Geological Survey of Canada. \\


        \hline
    \end{xltabular}

%\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

And here is the solution using [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals):

```
\documentclass[DIV=10]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cals, xcolor, caption, ragged2e, lipsum}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}


\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent


\begin{document}

{\RaggedRight
\captionaboveof{table}{Principais trabalhos referente à pesquisa sobre hidratos, contemplando primeiro, segundo e terceiro período de estudos - ordem cronológica de 1778 à 2005.}
\label{tb:periodos}
\begin{calstable}
% Defining column relativ to each other and relativ to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/16*3\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/16*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/16*9\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 16

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{1pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0pt}

% R1
\thead{\bfseries
\brow
    \cell{\textbf{Ano}}
    \cell{\textbf{Autor}}
    \cell{\textbf{Observações}} 
\erow
\mdseries
}
\tfoot{\lastrule}
\brow
    \cell{1778}
    \cell{Priestley}
    \cell{Primeiro indicativo da formação de hidratos de dióxido de enxofre ($SO_2$) através da realização de experimentos a baixas temperaturas.}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{1810}
    \cell{Davy}
    \cell{Descobriu hidratos de cloro, com experimentos acima do ponto de solidificação da água.}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{1823}
    \cell{Faraday}
    \cell{Identificou as propriedades dos hidratos de gás cloro, com fórmula $Cl_2$.10$H_2$O.}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{1877 e 1882}
    \cell{Cailletet e Bordet}
    \cell{Mediram pela primeira vez as propriedades dos hidratos gasosos mistos de $CO_2$ + $PH_3$ e de $H_2S$ + $PH_3$. }
\erow
\brow
    \cell{1883}
    \cell{Wroblewski}
    \cell{Identificou pela primeira vez o hidrato de dióxido de carbono.}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{1888 e 1890}
    \cell{Villard}
    \cell{Determinou a existência de hidratos de etano ($CH_4$), metano ($C_2$$H_6$) e propano ($C_3$$H_8$). E identificou o ponto quádruplo inferior.}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{1902}
    \cell{de Forcrand}
    \cell{Estabeleceu as temperaturas de equilíbrio a 1 atm de 15 hidratos.}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{1934 e 1939}
    \cell{Hammerschimidt}
    \cell{Identificou as causas do bloqueio de linhas de gás natural, sendo ocasionada por hidratos e descobriu os inibidores termodinâmicos.}
\erow
\brow
%
    \cell{1946}
    \cell{Deaton e Frost}
    \cell{Realizaram experimentos de formação de hidratos a partir de componentes puros e misturas de metano ($CH_4$), etano ($C_2$$H_6$) e propano ($C_3$$H_8$).}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{1949}
    \cell{Unruh e Katz}
    \cell{Reportaram as curvas de equilíbrio de hidratos para misturas de CO2 e CH4.}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{1951}
    \cell{Kobayashi et al.}
    \cell{Apresentaram dados experimentais para inibição de sistemas na presença de NaCl e etanol.}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{1951 e 1952}
    \cell{Claussen, Pauling e Marsh}
    \cell{Identificaram e nomearam duas diferentes estruturas cristalinas de hidratos como sI e sII.}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{1954}
    \cell{von Stackelberg e Müller}
    \cell{Confirmaram, através de difração de Raio X, as estruturas cristalinas sI e sII e classificaram hidratos de CO2 como sI. }
%
\brow
    \cell{1965 e 1974}
    \cell{Makogon}
    \cell{Documentou a descoberta de reservas de hidratos de metano na Sibéria, juntamente com a publicação do material Hidratos de Gás Natural.}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{1973}
    \cell{Davidson}
    \cell{produziu o material “Clatratos Hidratos” na Água: Um Tratado Abrangente.}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{1980}
    \cell{Kvenvolden e McMenamin}
    \cell{Descobriram a localização de hidratos em sedimentos rochosos no Alaska.}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{1987}
    \cell{Ripmeester et al.}
    \cell{Descobriram a existência da estrutura sH.}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{1990}
    \cell{Sloan}
    \cell{Produziu o material Clathrate Hidratos de Gases Naturais.}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{1995}
    \cell{Kvenvolden}
    \cell{Realizou um estudo sobre a análise da Geoquímica do Metano no Hidrato de Gás Natural.}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{1997}
    \cell{Spencer}
    \cell{Patenteou um método de separação seletiva de dióxido de carbono de sistemas multicomponentes.}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{2000}
    \cell{Seo et al.}
    \cell{Propuseram uma nova técnica de separação baseado em hidratos para recuperação do CO2 oriundo de combustão de motores.}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{2002}
    \cell{Mallik}
    \cell{Primeira produção viável de gás a partir de hidratos.}
\erow
\brow
    \cell{2005}
    \cell{Dallimore et al.}
    \cell{Realizou estudo “Relatório do experimento de campo internacional Mallik 5L sobre a recuperação de hidratos in situ do Permafrost”, relatório do Geological Survey of Canada.}
\erow
\makeatletter

\end{calstable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If there are not any tabular-like environment, there are no problems to break it.

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabto,parskip,mhchem}
\TabPositions{0.15\linewidth,0.4\linewidth}
\def\htab{\tab\hangindent.4\linewidth}
\begin{document}


\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\par
\textbf{Ano}\tab
\textbf{Autor}\htab
\textbf{Observações}\par 
\rule[1ex]{\linewidth}{.4pt}

1778\tab 
Priestley 
\htab Primeiro indicativo da formação de hidratos de dióxido de enxofre (\ce{SO2}) através da realização de experimentos a baixas temperaturas.

1810\tab
Davy\htab
Descobriu hidratos de cloro, com experimentos acima do ponto de solidificação da água.

1823\tab
Faraday\htab
Identificou as propriedades dos hidratos de gás cloro, com fórmula \ce{Cl2 * 10H2O}.

\ldots\tab
\ldots\htab
\ldots\ldots\ldots

\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}

\end{document}
```